# Why is block copy preferable to a strong reference when storing a block as a member variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Let's say we want to store SomeBlock

```
typedef void(^SomeBlock)(void);
```

in a private member variable of an object of type SomeClass in order to store it and run it later. We could do it this way:

```
//SomeClass.m

@implementation SomeClass{
    SomeBlock _someBlock;
}
//some code
@end
```

or we could do it this way:

```
//SomeClass.m
@interface SomeClass()
@property (nonatomic, copy) SomeBlock someBlock;
@end
```

According to http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/, the latter is preferable. Why?
Both examples are functional, but I wonder if there's some sort of memory implications I don't understand. There was some discussion around it in a non-ARC environment here: [Saving a block in instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343526/saving-a-block-in-instance-variable), but I am interested in using blocks as member variables in an ARC environment.

Comment: `SomeBlock * _someBlock;` would not have the `*`.

Comment: Where does that website say that the property is preferable? I just see syntax help.

Comment: It's just more modern to declare things as properties instead of declaring a bunch of ivars.

Comment: Closely related: [Blocks as strong pointers vs. copy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27152580), [Defining ObjC blocks as properties best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14649661), [What qualifier should I use to declare a block as an ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10128552)

Comment: (Although the second paragraph of my answer at that third link is wrong, I think.)

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell; you answered my question. Basically, you should be able to use the retained block just fine because ARC should handle it. But just in case they don't, it is a best practice to copy it to the heap, in the case that the block needs to outlive its lifetime in the stack.